# Can I create a socket server in C# that has a dynamic IP?

Tags: c#, sockets, dynamic-ip

As far as I know for a socket client to be able to connect to a socket server it needs to know the server's IP address.

But what happens when the server is using a dynamic IP address?

**Is it possible to connect to the server in any other way** (I don't think so)**?**

**Is there a way for me to let the client know the server's IP address automatically?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you investigate dynamic DNS? for instance [DynDNS](https://www.dyndns.com/)

Comment: You can also try VPN software like [hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/)

Comment: is this a public socket server or will it only be used within your network?

Comment: Hello Matthew. This will be a public server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to connect to the server in any other way (I don't think so)?

You could use a DNS name as well. There are some DNS providers which allow you to associate a fixed DNS name to a dynamic IP address. You may take a look at [dyndns](http://dyn.com/dns/).

> Is there a way for me to let the client know the server's IP address automatically?

The client needs an IP or DNS name.

Comment: It may be possible to use multi-cast, but that may also require more thought on the service design.

Comment: @Matthew Whited: You're not going to have working multi-cast unless you're on a local network or IPv6. Multi-cast generally doesn't work on the internet.

Answer (score -1):

you may store the dynamic IPs in some static IP data storage. the client will always know the static IP adress and from there he will take the dynamic adress.

Comment: Can you expand on this? Do you have any sources for this?

Comment: you may create a server application that runs on static IP which for instance knows the current IP adress of your MAIN server application (which has the dynamic IP). every time your IP changes - just save it in your static IP server.

Comment: "the client will always know the static IP adress and from there he will take the dynamic address" What?